# python - sieve of Eratosthenes when number is prime print "1" when not print "0"

Tags: python, function, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I must create a function `f(n)` which value is `1` when the number is prime or value is `0` when isn't prime.
Code is working but prints in revers order.
For example: `f(6)= 0 0 1 1 0 1 0`

```
def prime(n):
    if n<2: return False
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def f(n):
    print('0', end=' ')
    a=1
    while a<=n:
        n=n-1
        print('1' if prime(n) else '0', end=' ')

f(6)
```

Comment: That is _not_ a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It's just a loop counting down numbers and naively testing whether they are prime. But if you want to reverse the order of the output, just reverse the loop.

Comment: I don't  know how: while n>=a?

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3941967/764322) for a sieve example. What you have is just a very inefficient prime check.

Comment: I would also switch out n with sqrt(n). It'll save some time :)

Comment: Misleading title and tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the loop like:

```
def f(n):
  print('0')
  for a in range(1, n+1):
    print('1' if prime(a) else '0')
```

PS I have seen good examples of how to **actually** implement a sieve of Eratosthenes in python on Stack Overflow, worth searching for a better solution.