# Python - listing prime numbers from 1 to 1000 including 1

Tags: python

This program is for listing all the prime numbers between 1 and 1000, but my teacher would like me to include 1 in the results.

I tried to change it to say `if num >= 1:` and `for i in range(1,num)`, but then when I ran it, the only result was `1 is a prime number!`. Thanks!

```py
for num in range(1,1001):
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(f"{num} is a prime number!")
```

Comment: First thing would be, `if num >= 1:` after that, you have `if (num % i) == 0 break` that is why it is stopping there.

Comment: Weird.  When I run this, I get the expected output.

Comment: I'm also getting the expected result.

Comment: After you explain to your teacher what @StefanPochmann has mentioned, you may as well just `print(1,"is a prime number!")` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: As a sidenote, I would recommend you to look at the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm to find prime numbers, since it's a much more efficient solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python

Answer (score 1):

You should not write `for i in range(1, num):`, because `(any number) % 1 == 0`. `if num >= 1:` can also be removed, because it's always true.

Try the following code:

```
for num in range(1, 1001):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print num, 'is a prime number'
```

And remember, technically speaking, `1` isn't a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

Leave your code as is and above the main for loop add:

```
print("1 is a prime number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python solution: Print prime numbers from 1 to 1000

```
def prime():
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        for num in range(2, i):
            if i % num == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield i
```

To call the above function:

```
for i in prime():
    print(i, end=" ")
```

Comment: Hope it solves now

Answer (score -1):

```
a = int(input("enter the start number"))
b = int(input("enter the end number"))
for i in range(a,b+1):
    if i > 1:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(i,"is a prime number")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import math

n1 = 1000
run_lim = math.ceil(math.sqrt(n1))
prm_num = [2]

for i in range (1,n1+1) :
    if i == 1 :
        continue
    else :
        count = 0
        for j in range (len(prm_num)) : 

            if (prm_num[j] <= run_lim) and (i%prm_num[j]) == 0 :
                count += 1

        if count == 0 :
            prm_num.append(i)

print("The Prime Numbers are :- \n")
print(*prm_num, sep=",")
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import gmpy2

c = []
for i in range(1,1000):
    if gmpy2.is_prime(i)==True:
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```