# Is there a Python program that solves semi-primes?

Tags: python-2.7

so i have a formula that solves semi-primes faster than multiplying every pair of prime numbers over and over again! so instead of having to use long guess and check(shown below) you use basic division.

```
semi prime = 15 ... 2 * 3, 2 * 5, 2 * 7, 3 * 5 ... primes 3 and 5
```

and this is my way

```
semi prime = 15 ... 2 / 15, 3 / 15 ... primes ... primes 3 and 5
```

it does not change the length a lot here but it does in larger semi-primes. but now i wonder if there is a python program that can do this for me ? so far i can not make one but i am working on it.

Comment: mmm, factorize the number and check how many factor it have?

Comment: well, then just do that... what is the question again? check is a number is a semi-prime? or produce a list with all the semi-prime?

Comment: sorry i did not explain how it works. you need 4 variables (nth, prime 1,  number and prime 2),  set nth to 1, set number to nth prime number, set prime 1 to number, and set prime 2 to semi-prime / prime 1. If when you divide your semi-prime by prime 1 it comes out as a decimal then increase n by 1, making number go to the next prime number. repeat this until prime 2 comes out as a whole number. once it does prime 1 is your first prime and prime 2 is your second prime, if you want you can copy and paste this code into your environment and test it out.

Comment: the question was how do i factor out the two primes from a semi prime in a python program, or if there was already a code for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is to factorize the number, here is a example of how

```
def prime_generator(n):
    """produce all the prime numbers less or equal to n"""
    #put here the code for this

def prime_factorization(n):
    """return a list of with the all prime factors of n including their multiplicity""" 
    result=[]
    for p in prime_generator(n):
        while n%p==0: #while p divide n...
            result.append(p)
            n = n//p
        if n<=1:
            break
     return result

def is_semi_prime(n):
    factors = prime_factorization(n)   
    if len(factors) == 2:
        print n, "is a semi prime with those prime factors:", factors
    else:
        print n, "is not a semi-prime"

is_semi_prime( input("enter a number: ") )
```

the funny part here is the `prime_generator` it can be as simple as just filtering the numbers with a `is_prime` function like for example `filter(is_prime,xrange(2,n+1))`, or something more specialized like the [Sieve of Eratostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

EDIT

the above which use a general approach to the problem can be further improve by specialized the check, as semi prime number only have exactly two factors then we only need to find the first, remove it from the number and if whatever remain is prime we find it. For that we need a prime checking function and a generator of primes

```
def is_prime(n):
    #put here the code for this 


def prime_generator(n):
    #put here the code for this


def is_semi_prime(n):
    p1,p2 = 0,0
    for p1 in prime_generator(n):
        if n%p1==0:
            p2 = n//p1
            break
    if is_prime(p2):
        print n, "is a semi prime with those prime factors:", p1, p2
    else:
        print n, "is not a semi-prime"

is_semi_prime( input("enter a number: ") )
```

I think this is algorithm that you were trying to explain, as you can see don't need to search for the second prime (`p2`) only the first (`p1`) and the other will appear naturally if it exist.

I leave the two function needed as a exercise.

For `is_prime` you can use the simple trial division as you do in your answer which by the way fail to identify 2 as a prime, or a more powerful [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) like the [Miller-Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) ([Deterministic variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants))  (you can find a working version in http://rosettacode.org) or [Baillie-PSW test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test).

For the `prime_generator` you can use, as I mention before the Sieve of Eratostenes, or make a use of a infinite prime generator. You can find how in for example this question: [Sieve of eratosthenes finding primes python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python) and [how to implement an efficient infinite generator of prime numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python). The latter is my favorite

Comment: it gave me an error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Python Codes/Stack Overflow Test environment.py", line 23, in <module>
    is_semi_prime( input("enter a number: ") )
  File "/home/pi/Python Codes/Stack Overflow Test environment.py", line 17, in is_semi_prime
    factors = prime_factorization(n)
  File "/home/pi/Python Codes/Stack Overflow Test environment.py", line 8, in prime_factorization
    for p in prime_generator(n):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: of course it give error, you need to fill in the `prime_generator` code, I leave that as a exercise to you

Comment: OK i did it, but i still think i like my code better, it is shorter, to me less confusing, and it works at a decent speed up to a semi-prime as large as 25,000,000

Comment: bye ill be back at around 7:15, i live in springfield.MO

Comment: you know, we should be friends. we love looking at things differently, and trying to improve.

Comment: sure, we can be friend :)

Comment: I also aggregate more info to my answer

Comment: thanks that is exactly what i wanted! you know i am going to take some time and run it through some rsa challenge numbers just for the fun of it!

Answer (score 1):

NEVER MIND, I FIGURED IT OUT.

```
import math

running = True

prime_1 = 0
prime_2 = 0
semi_prime = 0

n = 0

semi_prime = input('Enter Semi-Prime: ')

while running:

    if prime_1 * prime_2 == semi_prime:

        print('your 2 primes are')
        print([prime_1])
        print([prime_2])
        running = False

    else:

        n += 1

        def is_prime(number):
              if number < 2:
                    return False
              if number % 2 == 0:
                    return False
              else:
                    for i in range(3, number):
                          if not number % i:
                                return False
                    return True



        #This array stores all the prime numbers found till n
        primes = []

        for i in range(100000):
              if is_prime(i):
                    primes.append(i)
              if len(primes) == n:
                    break

        print("next prime is " + str(primes[n-1]))

        prime_1 = primes[n-1]
        prime_2 = semi_prime / primes[n-1]
```

Comment: you usually define your function outside the loop, also you are repeating the job creating the list of primes over and over again for each iteration