# Prime factorisation program in python gives no output

Tags: python, prime-factoring

I am working on Project on Euler Problem 3,

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

The code that I came up with is as follows:

```
def q_prime(a):
    if a == 2:
            return True
    elif a < 2:
            return False

    for i in range(2,a):


            if a%i == 0:
                    return False
    else:
            return True


def prime_factor(x):
    prime_factors =[]
    for i in range(1,x):
            if q_prime(i) == True and x%i == 0:
                    prime_factors.append(i)
    return prime_factors
```

Calling this function of 13195 gave me [5,7,13,29] as expected. I tried some other combinations like 1035 which gives [3,5,23]. However, when I call this function on 600851475143, I get no output. Moreover, I get no error message either. It runs for a while, and simple restarts shell

I know this is not an elegant code, and I am guessing brute forcing my way through a problem like this for a large number is causing this problem? What exactly is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens when I try to run your code using Python 2.7:

```
$ python primes.py
Killed: 9
```

The issue is that `range(2, 600851475143)` tries to create a list of 600851475141 elements. This is too large to fit in your computer's memory, so the Python program gets killed.

You could try replacing `range()` with `xrange()`, but your program will take too long to complete. You need a better algorithm.

P.S. There's also a bug in your code which means that it doesn't work for prime inputs.

Comment: I see. So a better algorithm is required I guess? Back to the drawing board. What does "killed: 9" mean?

Comment: @getafix: 9 is the signal number for SIGKILL. The details are not super important here, but here is some info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGKILL

Answer (score 3):

Number 600851475143 is too big. You can simplify computations if in `q_prime` and in `prime_factor` you will check number not in range [2, n] bun in range [2, sqrt(n)+1]. This will also return correct result but takes less time:

```
import math

def q_prime(a):
    if a == 2:
            return True
    elif a < 2:
            return False

    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(a) + 1)):
            if a%i == 0:
                return False
    else:
        return True


def prime_factor(x):
    prime_factors =[]
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(x) + 1)):
            if q_prime(i) == True and x%i == 0:
                    prime_factors.append(i)
    return prime_factors
```

Comment: What's the rational behind choosing sqrt(n)?

Comment: @getafix if one divisor of number less then sqrt(n) then other is greater. And divisors of greater one also will be less then sqrt(n). So checking numbers greater than sqrt(n) is excessively.

Answer (score 2):

Both the functions that you have written are problematic given the size of the problem. `q_prime(a)` loops to `a` and `prime_factor(x)` loops to `x` calling `q_prime` every iteration. That makes your algorithm `O(N^2)` which is way too much for a number like `600851475143`.

Better approach (O(√N) -> essentially immediate result):

- generator function using [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python) yielding prime numbers
- loop through primes until `sqrt(n)` collecting factors while shrinking `n` with each factor found

  - add `n` itself if no other factors where found

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response, I tried implementing your suggestion (or at least my interpretation of it), would you mind taking a look? http://pastebin.com/PxTgsei6 It still doesn't work for the big number. Does this algorithm still scale as $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ Should I be using sets to speed things up?