# Printing prime number between a range. Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python

I've got all the numbers appended into list1 from x to y (inclusive). I now only need the list to contain only prime numbers from x to y inclusive

```
def primes(x , y):
    list1 = []
    for i in range(m, n + 1):
            list1.append(i)
    for elements in list1:
            if elements % 2 == 0:
                    pos = list1.index(elements)
                    list1.pop(pos)
    return list1
```

I've got all the numbers appended into list1 from x to y (inclusive) and also got rid of the even numbers but i cant seem to get rid of the other numbers that arent prime. I now only need the list to contain only prime numbers from x to y inclusive

For example x = 7, y = 23

list1 = [7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]

Thanks in advance

Comment: So in other words, you are at the very beginning and have trouble implementing the sieve algorithm. Please tell us what you don't understand about the sieve or/and where your troubles are trying to implement it.

Comment: Ive tried for elements in list1:
                if elements % 2 == 0:
                        pos = list1.index(elements)
                        list1.pop(pos)                                                                                                                 That gets rid of all the even numbers but i cant seem to get rid of the other ones that arent prime

Comment: There are tons of question in python relative to generation of prime numbers on SO. You should have a look at them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sieve of Eratosthenes - Finding Primes Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few tips: You don't need to generate the whole list of integer between x and y, and then remove the non-prime one. One faster approach is to generate all the prime numbers smaller than `y` and then remove those who are smaller than `x`. That way you can use the previously computed prime numbers to efficiently check if a number is a prime or not.

So let's start at the beginning. 2 is the only even prime number. So you can start from 2 and iterates over the odd number till `y`. A number will be prime if it is not divisible by any previous prime number.

For each number between 0 and `y`, you start with the assumption that it is a prime number. You check if it is divisible by the previous primes. If it is a multiple of any prime number then you can stop (`break`) since you know it is not a prime number. If it was not a multiple of any previous prime, then you add it to the list of prime numbers.

Finally once you have your list of prime numbers between 0 and `y`, you remove the elements smaller than `x`.

Which gives in Python:

```
def primes(x , y):
    l = [2] # list of prime numbers
    for n in range(3,y+1,2): # iterations over odd numbers
        isprime = True
        for e in l:
            if n % e == 0:
                isprime = False
                break
        if(isprime):
            l.append(n)

    return [e for e in l if e >= x]

print(primes(7,23))
# [7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
```