# I am trying to create the sieve of Eratosthenes in Python but the program still returns the original input. What is wrong?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the sieve of Eratosthenes here but the code keeps returning the original list. I have no idea what is wrong. Please do help a poor novice- and thank you very much in advance!!

```
def main():
    cupcake = []
    i = 0
    for i in range(1, 101):
        cupcake += [i]
    cupcake.remove(1)
    cupcake.insert(0, 0)
    for j in range(len(cupcake)):
        if cupcake[j] > 0:
            for k in range(len(cupcake)):
                if cupcake[k] > 0:
                    product = int(cupcake[k]) / int(cupcake[j])
                    if (type(product) is int) == True:
                        if product == 1:
                            continue
                        cupcake.remove(cupcake[k])
                        cupcake.insert((k-1), 0)
    print(cupcake)
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python

Answer (score 2):

```
product = int(cupcake[k]) / int(cupcake[j])
```

In this statement `product` will always be a float value, even if it is a whole number (2.0, ...). So the statement after it will always return false. You have to change the statement after it from

```
if (type(product) is int) == True:
```

to

```
if product.is_integer():
```

which uses the [float.is_integer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) functions.

Comment: An upvote or accepted answer would be thanks enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

That is awfully inefficient:

- you build the initial list one element at a time when a list comprehension would do it in one single operation: `cupcake = i for i in range(1, 101)` or even cupcake = list(range(1, 101))
- you use the anti-pattern `remove` + `insert` to change the value of an element of the list: `cupcake[0] = 0` and later in the code `cupcake[k] = 0`
- you loop from the begining for j and k, when the second loop could start at j+1
- you (wrongly) use division when you should use modulo

And your real problem is that in Python 3, the division of two integers is always a float whether one is or is not a multiple of the other:

```
>>> 4 / 2
2.0
>>> type(4/2)
float
```

So your code could become:

```
def main():
    cupcake = list(range(1, 101))
    cupcake[0] = 0
    for j in range(len(cupcake)):
        if cupcake[j] > 0:
            for k in range(j+1, len(cupcake)):
                if cupcake[k] > 0:
                    if cupcake[k] % cupcake[j] == 0:
                        cupcake[k] = 0
    print(cupcake)
```

Anyway, the correct algo is to remove multiples instead of consistently testing divisibility:

```
def main():
    cupcake = list(range(1, 101))
    cupcake[0] = 0
    for j in range(len(cupcake)):
        if cupcake[j] > 0:
            for k in range(j + cupcake[j], len(cupcake), cupcake[j]):
                        cupcake[k] = 0
    print(cupcake)
```

Comment: Hi Serge- thanks for you answer. Wow- I didn't quite expect there to be such a short way. I'm making my way through my first-ever coding exercises- please do bear with me. Hope to be as good as you sometime ^^

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't write it like that but here goes my improvement suggestion for your code:

```
def main():
     cupcake = [i for i in range(101)]
     cupcake.remove(0)
     cupcake.remove(1)
     for j in cupcake:
         if j > 0:
             for k in cupcake:
                 if k > j and k % j == 0:
                     cupcake.remove(k)
     print(cupcake)

main()
```

Comment: Woah this is short. Will be experimenting with this. Thanks Veltz!