# Determining Prime numbers using nested while loops in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have this prime numbers program to solve: given a max input, I am to determine all the prime numbers between 2 and the max input inclusive, using a while loop inside a while loop.
I know this would be simpler using a range and/or math functions but for the purposes of this assignment I need to use while-loops.

Testing the code below with `max = 5` outputs `2,3,4`.
Correct output is `2,3,5`.

```
max = int(input('Enter the max integer: '))
start_number = 2

while start_number <= max:
    interval_number = start_number
    while interval_number <= max: 
        if max % interval_number != 0: 
            print(interval_number)
            interval_number += 1
    start_number += 1
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using keywords for your variable names. variables like `max`, `min`, `file`, or any other word that your python editor highlights should not be used as variable names. what happens when you want to use the `max` function afterwards? you will get `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easier to use for loops. This program assumes that a number is prime, and then checks everything up to the number.

```
max = int(input('Enter the max integer: '))
for number in range(2, max+1): 
    is_prime = True
    for interval_num in range(2, number):
        if number % interval_num == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break
      
    if is_prime:
        print(number)
```

[Live DEMO](https://repl.it/repls/MidnightblueWobblyPlane)

---

If you must however, use while loops, here you go. It's the same logic:

```
max = int(input('Enter the max integer: '))
possiblePrime = 2
while possiblePrime < max+1: 
    isPrime = True
    num = 2
    while num < possiblePrime:
        if possiblePrime % num == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
        num += 1
      
    if isPrime:
        print(possiblePrime)

    possiblePrime += 1
```

[Live DEMO](https://repl.it/repls/BlandQualifiedBetatest)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python). If you want to use two nested `while` loops, then consider that for each number you really need to check for the divisibility up to the square root of the current number. Hence somewhere you will have a condition of the type `while factor * factor <= current_number:`.