# What is the bug in my code for find the prime number list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get a prime number list. 15 should not occur as per the definition of prime number. But it showed on my output. I don't know what happened.
`python`

```
import math
n = input('n')
n = int(n)

A = list(range(2,n+1))
print(A)
n_=math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
m = list(range(2,n_+1))
for i in range(0,len(m)):
    if m[i]!=0:
        j = m[i]^2
        while j<= n:
            A[j-2] = 0
            j = j+m[i]


A[0]=2;
print(A)
print(m)
```

I expect the output to be [2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0]

Actual output is [2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: What method are you trying to use? Kinda looks like a sieve but I'm confused...

Comment: sorry the expected output should be [2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0], something happens with 3, but I could not find out the problem. lol

Comment: But what math do you rely on?

Comment: It's a sieve !! sorry for forgetting to mention that

Comment: well ... 7 is a prime, 13 is a prime, 19 is a prime, ...

Comment: Ok fine, then I think you've got a problem on the math side of things. Take a look a the wikipedia page for sieve of erathostene for a great pseudocode

Comment: Thank you... I am just starting to learn algorithms. I implement the pseudocode as per the pseudocode on the book, but it didn't give me the right answer lol. Maybe I didn't really catch the idea lol Thanks again for pointing out the error. I'll check wikipedia :D

Comment: [sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python)

Comment: finally I found that I made a mistake in m[i]^2 it seems that it isn't m[i] square, I mix up matlab and python lol

Comment: Yeah, Python exponentiation is `**`.