# Project Euler task #10 Python wrong answer

Tags: python

The task [Project Euler #10](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10) is: The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

I'm confused by why is my code giving me a wrong answer of `1000000000001`. 
Here it is:

```
def prime(a):
    for i in range(2,a):
        if a % i == 0:
            return False
            break
        return True

sum = 2
for n in range(3,2000000,2):
    if prime(n):
        sum += n
print(sum)
```

Could someone explain me what is exactly wrong with it?

Comment: Your `prime` method is incorrect. It will return `True` for any number not divisible by `2`. It never reaches the second iteration of the loop.

Comment: The task is to find the sum of all the primes below two million

Comment: Quick efficiency point - you only need to check divisors up to the square root of a number to test for being prime.

Answer (score 3):

You returned too early from the for loop:

```
def prime(a):
    if a < 2:
        return False
    if a == 2:
        return True
    for i in range(2,a):
        if a % i == 0:
            return False
    # should be after checking all numbers
    return True # this line
```

Besides you only need to check up to `sqrt(a)` and exclude even numbers.

```
import math

# skip even numbers
def prime(a):
    if a == 2:
        return True
    if a % 2 == 0:
        return False
    n = math.ceil(math.sqrt(a))
    for i in range(3, n+1, 2):
        if a % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: this is giving wrong solution `k = sum([i for i in range(2,2000000) if prime(i)])+2`

Comment: @prashantrana which function? I fixed the second one.

Comment: i used the earlier second one, now the solution is right

Answer (score 0):

copying @MrHIDEn solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python)

```
def get_primes(n):
  m = n+1
  numbers = [True] * m 
  for i in range(2, int(n**0.5 + 1)):
    if numbers[i]:
      for j in range(i*i, m, i):
        numbers[j] = False
  primes = []
  for i in range(2, m):
    if numbers[i]:
      primes.append(i)
  return primes


primes = get_primes(2000000)
print(sum(primes))
```

output

```
142913828922
```

reference: [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) this algorithm is faster